# Ubuntu16.04 boot to black screen in vmware workstation

Tags: lightdm, vmware

when i open virtual machine it will be blank screen and cursor
[like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Qe7v.png)

i have  tried:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
sudo shutdown -r now
```

it doesn't work
my english not very good,So the problem statement is not very clear

Answer (score 0):

I find that my nvidia driver has problem,when i input

```
lshw -c video
```

it show

```
*-display
description: VGA compat ible controller
product: SVGA II Adapter
vendor: VMware
physical id: f
bus info: pc 1@0000:00:0f .0
version: 00
width: 32 bits
clock: 33MHZ
capabilities: vga_ controller bus_ master cap_ list rom
conf igurat ion: dr iver=vmwgfx latency=64
resources: irg:16 ioport: 1070(size=16) memory: e8000000-efffffff memory: fe000000-fe7fffff memo
ry :c0000-dffff
```

and when i open floder /prov/driver
it doesn't have nvidia

```
root @zwq-v irtual-machine /p/driver# lS
rtc
```

so how can i install nvidia driver